# Piping into moreutils' ts with nanosecond precision?

Tags: date, timestamps

On this system:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS \n \l
$ uname -a
Linux mypc 3.19.0-56-generic #62~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 11 11:03:33 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
$ apt-show-versions -r moreutils
liblist-moreutils-perl:i386/trusty 0.33-1build3 uptodate
moreutils:i386/trusty 0.50 uptodate
```

... I can use `date` with a nanosecond precision, no problem:

```
$ date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S'
20160327133441
$ date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S%N'
20160327133446582969969
```

... however, if I use the same format string with `moreutils`' `ts`, the nanosecond precision fails:

```
$ ping google.com | ts '%Y%m%d%H%M%S%N'
20160327133829%N PING google.com (216.58.209.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
20160327133829%N 64 bytes from arn06s07-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.110): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=32.0 ms
20160327133830%N 64 bytes from arn06s07-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.110): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=31.6 ms
^C
```

Any way to get `ts` to show nano- (or micro-) second precision when prepending timestamps to stdin?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Starting from moreutils 0.31 `%.S` specifier is available, use it instead of %S :

```
ping google.com | ts '%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%.S'
20160327-15:01:11.361885 PING google.com (216.58.209.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
20160327-15:01:11.362056 64 bytes from bud02s22-in-f206.1e100.net (216.58.209.206): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=26.3 ms
20160327-15:01:12.314243 64 bytes from bud02s22-in-f206.1e100.net (216.58.209.206): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=26.2 ms
20160327-15:01:13.315651 64 bytes from bud02s22-in-f206.1e100.net (216.58.209.206): icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=26.3 ms
```

Comment: That's nice - great there is a solution; cheers @Tagwint!

Comment: Just want to add a reference: https://manpages.debian.org/testing/moreutils/ts.1.en.html "In addition to the regular strftime conversion specifications, "%.S" and "%.s" and "%.T" are like "%S" and "%s" and "%T", but provide subsecond resolution"

Answer (score 4):

As of v0.62, the `%T` format specifier also comes in a high-resolution variety with a dotted name, which is `%.T` :

```
% ( for i in {1..5}; do date +'%T.%N'; sleep 0.7; done ) | ts '[%F %.T]' 
[2021-04-14 12:31:30.655183] 12:31:30.613979000
[2021-04-14 12:31:31.330801] 12:31:31.329998000
[2021-04-14 12:31:32.046576] 12:31:32.046036000
[2021-04-14 12:31:32.763263] 12:31:32.762500000
[2021-04-14 12:31:33.478184] 12:31:33.477380000
```